# How can I store a variable (Int) permanently after app closes and Display it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to store a variable named *total* which holds the number of rows in `UITableView`. Since the user types strings for UITableView, the variable is *listTable* which is String array.

I have my *total* as total = listTable.count

ISSUE:

Every time the app launches it displays 0 as number of rows used, however once you go to the UITableView ViewController and come back to the main ViewController it automatically corrects its self to the current amount of rows.

Code Used:

```
 import UIKit
    var listTable = [String]()
    var total = listTable.count
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var numberOfRows: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var TypeToCreateRow: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var AddRow: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            total = listTable.count

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(total, forKey: "rows")

            let showRow =    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("rows")!
            numberOfRows.text = "\(showRow)"
            print(showRow)



            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
 @IBAction func RowAdd(sender: UIButton) {
            listTable.append(TypeToCreateRow.text!)

            TypeToCreateRow.text = " "


           numberOfRows.text = "\(total)" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:value forKey:@"key"];
```

and to find it after :

```
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [user objectForKey:@"login"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the object first before reading it. That's why you write 0 first and read it immediately.

These two lines don't achieve anything.

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(total, forKey: "rows")
let showRow =    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("rows")!
```

You need to `setObject` after you have the correct value, later in code. Not at the start.

Also as JAL mentioned you should use `setInteger` instead of object, as it is more optimized.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't be force-unwrapping a the result of `objectForKey`.  This will cause a crash if the value returned from `NSUserDefaults` is `nil`.  2. Because `listTable.count` returns an `Int`, the OP should be using `setInteger` not `setObject`.

Comment: Please read my answer. I sad that this is NOT how you do it. I only used those two lines as a quote to inform him that they do not work.

Comment: Then your answer does not add value.

Comment: I did mention that he needs to add it after he has the correct value.